# What Distribution Has This CDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Does the probability distribution with the CDF:

$$F(x)=1-(1-x^b)^\frac{1}{b}$$
where $x\in[0,1]$ and $b\in[0,\infty)$ have a name? Is this a known distribution?

Comment: Please add some context.

Comment: @StubbornAtom, I created it visually. I figured somebody had already used this before somewhere but I don't recognize the CDF. It doesn't match any distributions I'm familiar with. I was curious to see if it has a name.

Comment: It looks like a [Pareto type IV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Pareto_types_I%E2%80%93IV), or a [Generalized Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution#Exponentiated_generalized_Pareto_distribution)  or [Burr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution) distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to notice is that the support of such a distribution is on $X \in [0,1]$, thus ruling out most options.  The density is $$f_X(x) = x^{b-1} (1-x^b)^{1/b - 1},$$ which is vaguely reminiscent of a beta distribution.  Indeed, if we take the usual beta distribution $Y \sim \operatorname{Beta}(r,s)$ with density $$f_Y(y) = \frac{\Gamma(r+s)}{\Gamma(r)\Gamma(s)} y^{r-1} (1-y)^{s-1}, \quad y \in [0,1]$$ and transform it with $X = Y^{1/b}$, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
f_X(x) &= f_Y(x^b) bx^{b-1} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(r+s)}{\Gamma(r)\Gamma(s)} x^{b(r-1)} (1 - x^b)^{s-1} bx^{b-1} \\
&= b \frac{\Gamma(r+s)}{\Gamma(r)\Gamma(s)} x^{br - 1}(1 - x^b)^{s-1}. 
\end{align}$$

Then the specific choice of parameters $r = 1$, $s = 1/b$, yields the target density:

$$f_X(x) = b\frac{\Gamma(1/b+1)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1/b)} x^{b-1} (1-x^b)^{1/b-1} = x^{b-1}(1-x^b)^{1/b-1},$$

since $\Gamma(1/b+1) = \frac{1}{b} \Gamma(1/b)$.  So we can recognize $X$ as following a transformed $\operatorname{Beta}(1,1/b)$ distribution where the transformation is $X = Y^{1/b}$.  This also happens to be a special case of the [Kumaraswamy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution) which is parameterized as
$$f_X(x \mid a, b) = ab x^{a-1} (1-x^a)^{b-1}.$$  In your special case, we have $$X \sim \operatorname{Kumaraswamy}(b, 1/b).$$

Comment: Great work, thank you